# Query to Check for Values Not Matching List in Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am writing a SQL query that uses the IN operator in the WHERE clause on a table that contains millions of records.

I would like to know for the specific values I am checking in my WHERE clause, which ones are missing from the table.

How do I write a query to check for the values that do not result in a match according to the values in my WHERE clause for those values specifically?

For example -

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees
WHERE emp_id IN (123, 456, 789)
```

Let's say that this query returns 2 rows for emp_id = 123 and emp_id = 456.

I want to write a query that shows me what was missing, illustrating that there was no row in the table specifically for emp_id = 789.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result/

Comment: @D-Shih - Yes, I have added sample data and what I am expecting.

Answer (score 1):

To find rows missing, you must have a canonical set of rows to compare with. Here's an example using the [VALUES statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) (which is new in MySQL 8.0).

Suppose we have a list 1, 2, 19, 64 and we want to find which ones *don't* have matching rows in the table `mytable`.

```
SELECT t.column_0
FROM (VALUES ROW(1), ROW(2), ROW(19), ROW(64)) AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable ON t.column_0 = mytable.id
WHERE mytable.id IS NULL;
```

If you use a version older than MySQL 8.0, you can replace the derived table with this more verbose syntax:

```
...
FROM (SELECT 1 AS column_0 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 19 UNION SELECT 64) AS t
...
```

Or you could also create a temporary table and fill it with the values you want to search for, one value per row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opposite of IN which is NOT IN(). Keep the bit inside the brackets the same and you'll get every record that doesn't have that

Comment: That is correct, but doesn't answer the question: "which ones are missing from the table."

Comment: That doesn't work for me as I only want to know about the results where they are missing from the table per the list that is in my WHERE clause.